# NodeJS pre-signed URLs for Secure S3 Downloads - Help w/simple spec

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, cryptography, sha256

Looking for some review of this flow so I can pinpoint where the signing calculation is going wrong.

The main issue is in generating the signing key and signature--the hashing of the canonical request seems to match the reference here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html

The sha256hmac and getSignature functions look like this:

```
function sha256hmac(key, string, encoding = 'hex') {
  return crypto.createHmac('sha256', key).update(string, 'utf8').digest(encoding);
};

function getSignature(stringToSign, signingDates) {

  const dateKey              = sha256hmac('AWS4' + S3_SECRET_KEY, signingDates.shortDate);
  const dateRegionKey        = sha256hmac(dateKey, S3_REGION);
  const dateRegionServiceKey = sha256hmac(dateRegionKey, S3_SERVICE);
  const signingKey           = sha256hmac(dateRegionServiceKey, S3_REQUEST_TYPE);

  const signature = sha256hmac(signingKey, stringToSign);

  return signature;

}
```

Thanks for looking!

Comment: Why are you Hex encoding at every step of the way? You should use Buffers except for the very last HMAC invocation.

Comment: @ArtjomB. THANK YOU. Totally glossed over that the introduction of a default hex encoding destroyed the chaining. Thanks again! You should do an answer so I can mark it.

Comment: You probably already have changed your code so that it works. You can post your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

The fix:

```
// remove default hex encoding
function sha256hmac(key, string, encoding) {
  return crypto.createHmac('sha256', key).update(string, 'utf8').digest(encoding);
};

function getSignature(stringToSign, signingDates) {

  // do not supply an encoding argument to sha256hmac()
  // each of these return a buffer
  const dateKey              = sha256hmac('AWS4' + S3_SECRET_KEY, signingDates.shortDate);
  const dateRegionKey        = sha256hmac(dateKey, S3_REGION);
  const dateRegionServiceKey = sha256hmac(dateRegionKey, S3_SERVICE);
  const signingKey           = sha256hmac(dateRegionServiceKey, S3_REQUEST_TYPE);

  // output hex encoding here
  const signature = sha256hmac(signingKey, stringToSign, 'hex');

  return signature;

}
```

Did not fully grok this from https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_hmac_digest_encoding

> Calculates the HMAC digest of all of the data passed using
>   hmac.update(). The encoding can be 'hex', 'latin1' or 'base64'. If
>   encoding is provided a string is returned; otherwise a Buffer is
>   returned;
>
> The Hmac object can not be used again after hmac.digest() has been
>   called. Multiple calls to hmac.digest() will result in an error being
>   thrown.